# Java definition and API element in documentation.

Tags: java

I have simply one question(maybe stupid) but it's not clear for me. According to the java documentation:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/intro/definition.html
we can read that Java platform consists of two elements:

- JVM
- Java API

Below that information we have phrase "The API is a large collection of ready-made software components that provide many useful capabilities. It is grouped into libraries of related classes and interfaces"

My question is what does it mean "related classes". I have thought that API means only interfaces.

Comment: API means 'Application Programming Interface', which doesn't mean `interface` in the Java sense.

Answer (score 1):

API means all artifacts and conventions available for public usage:

- interfaces
- classes
- enums
- resources
- usage contracts and conventions

Answer (score 1):

In written material which is not code, the word "interface" does not always refer to a Java `interface` type.

The more general meaning of "interface" is any publicly visible set of methods, possibly in multiple classes.  The "I" in API refers to that connotation of the word "interface."  That's why it includes Java classes which are not Java `interface` types.

Comment: So related classes are java core libraries? So if interface means interfaces and related classes what are java related classes forJMS API(I ask beacause it has a lot of implementations, so I'm not sure what it means JMS API in this context)

Comment: Any single API, including the JMS API, consists of its own publicly documented packages and classes.  So, [javax.jms.ObjectMessage](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/ObjectMessage.html) is part of the JMS API, but implementation classes, such as com.sun.messaging.jmq.jmsclient.ObjectMessageImpl, are not.  The JMS API depends on Java SE, but does not include Java SE.

Comment: Thank you for your patient :) So java core libraries is just Java API, right? According to that phrase from wikipedia "An API specification can take many forms, including ... the libraries of a programming language"

Comment: "Java API" usually refers to the publicly documented packages and classes of the core Java libraries, yes.  "Java SE API" would be a more accurate term.